# Warning Pop-Up Window Before Saving

Tags: 2013, javascript, infopath, jquery, designer-workflow

I do not know which way to turn.  The scenario is that I have created a SharePoint List with a InfoPath form attached to the list.  There are numerous individuals that will be touching the form per line item. So even if I add required fields once the required has been selected the next individuals will not remember to look at the required field.  So a way I was thinking to avoid those mistakenly missing the required field, I want to add a warning pop-up (Alert Function) to the form.  The alert window would pop-up and remind the user to satisfy the required field.

I found others way that this can be done but not sure which way to take.  I know you can use a AJAX to work with InfoPath.  Also, to add an alert function to the Save Button.

What I would want to do is add an alert to the Save button created InfoPath not sure how to do this.  Or should I create another view and have the view appear once the for is Save?  The thing I forgot to mention I do not want the user to be able to save before the alert is shown.  So the alert will appear if the user clicks save.  Click OK in the alert and then presses save again to save the form.

Can someone guide me to the best answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a formatting rule on the save button in InfoPath that says If `[Required Field] is blank > Disable (or hide) this control`.

That way, if your required field is not entered, the button will not appear or be able to submit.

Additionally, you could have a section with text near your save button that says `Please complete [Required Field] before continuing` that you can hide using the format rule with opposite logic - `If [Required Field] is not empty > Hide this control`.

You can also set validation on your [Required Field] that comes with it's own pop up box if the field doesn't meet the criteria you set.

All of these options together should ensure your users don't forget to fill in the required field!

Here's a walk through for further support: https://www.eimagine.com/conditionally-requiring-a-field-in-an-infopath-form/

Hope that helps.